# Ember-CLI Application + Working with Ember-CLI Addon

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-addon

So I have this Ember-CLI Application that I am working on that has a shared resource Ember-CLI Addon that it uses. I am developing on both of them at the same time.

I was wondering if there was any way to setup the Application to auto reload when changes are made the the Addon. They are linked up via "npm link." It would be awesome if I can develop on the Addon and instantly see the changes within the Application without having to stop/restart the server.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running `ember build --watch` in the addon's root directory? This will rebuild the addon after every edit.  You will of have to rebuild the main app afterwards - which you can trigger by `touch`-ing any of your app's files.

Answer (score 1):

This thread is a little old, but in case someone stumbles across this and wants an answer. 
If you add the following to index.js of your addon:

```
isDevelopingAddon: function() {
    return true;
}
```

e.g.

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'my-addon',
    isDevelopingAddon: function() {
        return true;
    }
};
```